# Does gasoline ruin an air filter?

Tags: honda, motorcycle, air-filter

The carburetor on my 2005 Honda Shadow Aero (VT750C) had a bad leak and flooded the air cleaner assembly with gasoline.  The air filter was completely soaked with gas, so I let it air dry.  Is my filter ruined, or is it okay now that it's dry?

Comment: Carburetor on a 2005 Honda? How's that? I wouldn't think they'd be using one on cars now for many years ...

Comment: @Paulster2 It's a motorcycle. Though not too long ago they're putting fuel injection on motorcycles too.

Comment: I should have read closer. This is why I leave stupid comments instead of really stupid answers sometimes :-) thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 8):

If it was just a normal paper filter it is fine. If it is a re-usable washable filter then then I would suggest a wash and oiling procedure according to the manufacturer instructions.

Answer (score 1):

The last vehicle in the USA to use a carb was the Susuki Jimmy in 1993. Your air filter element is bonded together with petro-chemical adhesives, and a lot of filters have a petro-chemical treatment to enhance thier performance. Soaking the filter in petrol can only be detrimental to the filter. Your best bet is to change the filter to avoid any possibility of it breaking pieces off and causing problems in the manifold or throttle body.

Comment: This is not necessarily true at all. For starters, the Kawasaki Ninja 500 was produced all the way through 2009, and uses a carb, like many other *motorcycles*. The air filters on most of these bikes, similarly, are to be coated in motor oil (a petro-chemical) upon installation.

Comment: The Honda Aero in Europe is an estate car, which I literally took it to be, most people would understand vehicle to be a car or truck. As far as it goes for motor cycles the hydro-carbon emmissions could be as high as 90 times that of an SUV, but since 2010 the emmissions standards have become increaseingly more stringent. This means that an oil soaked air filter would not be used on late models as it would draw hydro-carbons (the oil) into the engine and allow those emmissions.

Answer (score -1):

I think you must have to mention it on bike Because carburetor is being used in them mostly and if its leaked than you must first air dry the filter after oiling procedure and then check it out by putting it back. But it would be better to replace it.

Comment: Dent - welcome to Mechanics.SE. This may just be a language issue, but your post doesn't appear to answer the question. Can you clarify.